# Pandas groupby on concatenated groupby objects

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the groupby and sum to quickly aggregate accros two data sets

A which contains:

```
sequence shares
1        100
2        200
3        50
1        200
```

B which contains:

```
sequence shares
1        100
2        200
2        50
3        50
```

I am using `A=A.groupby(['sequence']).sum()` and `B=B.groupby(['sequence']).sum()` to sum the shares across each sequence. I then want to concatenate these sets again and sum the shares across sequences. However, I try using `C = concat([A,B])` and now find that I only have the column shares as an index and cannot group by sequence. `C.group(['sequence']).sum()` gives me an error KeyError: u'no item named sequence'.

What I would like to get out is C:

```
sequence shares
1        400
2        450
3        100
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here? I could concatenate before groupby().sum() but I really want to knock these data sets down to smaller sizes before concatenating them.

Answer (score 5):

The `groupby` method returns a dataframe indexed by `'sequence'`.  When adding two dataframes, the rows are aligned by the indices.  In this case, the indices for grpA and grpB are both `'sequence'` so the resulting DataFrame C adds the appropriate rows together.

```
A = DataFrame({'sequence': [1,2,3,1], 'shares': [100,200,50,200]})
B = DataFrame({'sequence': [1,2,2,3], 'shares': [100,200,50,50]})

grpA = A.groupby('sequence').sum()
grpB = B.groupby('sequence').sum()

In [60]: grpA + grpB
Out[60]:
          shares
sequence
1            400
2            450
3            100
```

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please accept it as the solution.  Thanks!